# Minimize $\mathrm{E}(U-bV-a)^{2}$, $U=\sum_{i=1}^{3}X_{i}.\, V=\sum_{i=1}^{3}i X_{i}\quad X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}\in N(1,1)$ i.i.d. r.v

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

> Let $X_{1}, X_{2}$ and $X_{3}$ be independent , $N(1,1)$-distributed random variables. Set $U=X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}$ and $V=X_{1}+2X_{2}+3X_{3}$. Determine the constants $a$ and $b$ so that $\mathrm{E}(U-a-bV)^{2}$ is minimized.

Here is what I did

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    U-bV\in N(B\mu,B\Lambda B^{T})\\
        \mathrm{E}((U-bV)-a)^{2}\\
        \frac{d}{d a}  \mathrm{E}((U-bV)-a)^{2}=-2\mathrm{E}(U-bV)+2a=2(a-\mathrm{E}(U-bV))\\
         \mu= \left[\begin{array}{c}
            U  \\
            bV 
    \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
             1&1& 1  \\
             b&2b&3b 
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
             1  \\
             1\\
             1
        \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
             3  \\
             6b 
        \end{array}\right]\\
        B\mu=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
           1  & -1
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
             3  \\
             6b 
        \end{array}\right]=\left[3-6b\right]\\
        2(a-\mathrm{E}(U-bV))=2(3-6b-a)
   \end{split}
\end{equation*}

My book gives the answer

\begin{equation*}
b=a=\frac{3}{7}\Leftrightarrow 2(3-6b-a)=0
\end{equation*}
which of course works. But is there any reason that this is the *only* solution? Is there any reason for example

\begin{equation*}
b=\frac{1}{3},\, a=1\quad \text{or}\quad  b=-1,\, a=9
\end{equation*}

wouldn't work as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply out $\mathrm{E}(U-a-bV)^{2} $ keeping $ U $ and $ V $. Differentiate wrt $ a $ to get an equation involving $ a $ and $ b $ in terms of expectations of $ U $ and $ V $. Do the same for $ b $. You then have two simultaneous equations in $ a $ and $ b $.

Solve for $ a $ and $ b$. You should get..

$ \hat b = Cov (U,V)/Var(V) $

$ \hat a = E(U)-\hat bE(V) $

This agrees with the usual least squares result.

Next, plug in the values of $ U $ and $ V $ in terms of the $ X_i $.

$ Cov (X_i, X_j) = 0 $ if $ i \ne j $.
$ Cov (X_i, X_i) = Var(X_i) $

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
U,V\in N(\mu,\Lambda)\\
\mu=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
             1&1& 1  \\
             1&2&3 
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
             1  \\
             1\\
             1
        \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
             3  \\
             6
        \end{array}\right]\\
\Lambda= \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
            1 & 1& 1 \\
           1  & 2& 3
        \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
          1   &1  \\
           1  & 2\\
           1& 3
        \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
          3   &  6\\
           6  & 14
        \end{array}\right]\\
    \mathrm{E}((U-a)-bV)^{2}=\mathrm{E}\Big[(U-a)^{2}-2b(U-a)V+b^{2}V^{2}\Big]\\
    =\mathrm{E}\Big[U^{2}-2aU+a^{2}-2bUV+2baV+b^{2}V^{2}\Big]\\
    =\mathrm{E}(U^{2})-2a\mathrm{E}(U)+a^{2}-2b\mathrm{E}(UV)+2ba\mathrm{E}(V)+b^{2}\mathrm{E}(V^{2})\\
    \mathrm{E}(U)=3,\quad \mathrm{E}(V)=6,\qquad \mathrm{Var}(U)=\mathrm{E}(U^{2})-(\mathrm{E}(U))^{2}\\
    \mathrm{Var}(V)=\mathrm{E}(V^{2})-(\mathrm{E}(V))^{2}\\
    \mathrm{E}(U^{2})=3+(3)^{2}=12\\
    \mathrm{Var}(V^{2})=14+(6)^{2}=50\\
    \mathrm{Cov}(U,V)=\mathrm{E}(UV)-\mathrm{E}(U)\mathrm{E}(V)\\
    \mathrm{E}(UV)=6+3\cdot 6=24\\
      \mathrm{E}((U-a)-bV)^{2}=12-6a+a^{2}-48b+12ba+50b^{2}\\
      \frac{d}{da}\mathrm{E}((U-a)-bV)^{2}=0=-6+2a+12b\\
      a=\frac{-6+12b}{-2}=3-6b\\
 \frac{d}{db}\mathrm{E}((U-a)-bV)^{2}=0=-48+12a+100b\\
=-48+12(3-6b)+100b\\
=-12+28b\\
\frac{3}{7}=b\\
a=3-6(\frac{3}{7})=\frac{3\cdot 7-3\cdot 6}{7}=\frac{3}{7}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}